# CakePHP : login using ID only (not username + password)

Tags: cakephp, authentication, passwords

I'm new to CakePHP and OOP in general. I'm following this tutorial from the official website that teaches me how to make a blog : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Problem is, I'd like to be able to **make users log in using only an ID field**, instead of the classic username-password duo.

But I can't find a way to do it... From what I saw, Auth Component always requires two fields. How should I proceed ? I'm lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not a good idea, but way to do this is simple.

Used version: CakePHP v3.4.5

Templates\Users\login.ctp:

```
<form method="post" action="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'Users', 'action' => 'login']) ?>">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="">
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Controller\UsersController.php:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->findById($this->request->getData()['id'])->first();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'MyAction']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Id not found.');
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Dont forget about loading AuthComponent in AppController and allow login method for non-authorized users - what was described [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

Comment: That's perfect ! Thank you very much. :)